# how to write an if-statement in python that incorporates platform.platform

Tags: python, if-statement

i am trying to write a program that prints different things depending on the OS and i'm wanting to write an if-statement to do that.I'm new to python but after looking online for a bit i haven't been able to find any solution

```
import platform

print('platform:', platform.platform())

if platform.platform == mac0S:
    print('this is a mac')
```

Comment: Presumably `macOS` is supposed to be a string: `if platform.platform() == "macOS"`

Comment: Also you forgot the parentheses `()` after `platform.platform`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be completing the previous answers and giving some examples.

So first of all you're going to want to check the `platform` [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html)

There you'll find that [`platform.platform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.platform) is a function that returns a single string, but it includes the MacOS version, which doesn't suit your example, so we'll be using `platform.system` instead: It returns `Windows`, `Linux` or `Darwin` (for OSX).

```py
import platform

print(platform.system())

if platform.system() == "Darwin":
    print("This is a Mac")
elif platform.system() == "Windows":
    print("This is a Windows")
elif platform.system() == "Linux":
    print("This is a lean, mean, Linux machine")
```

Hope this helps!